# Should the Gemora allow boiled food on Pesach?

Tags: passover, cooking-bishul, chametz-leaven, maseches-pesachim

[Pesachim 39B](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=39b&format=pdf) quotes a Beraisa which says, "The following do not become Chametz: something (i.e. grain) that was already baked (matzo), ***cooked***, or Chalut (scalded, I guess?) in boiling water."

Then the Gemorah asks a question how it could be cooked, since while the water would be heating up the grains (or flour?) would become Chametz, to which it answers that it means something that was baked and cooked.

However, I am not comfortable with the Gemorah's answer. It already said that something baked cannot become Chametz. Something that was baked and something that was baked then boiled have both been baked. So if that's what the Beraisa actually meant, it was redundant (not to mention misleading).

Furthermore, another answer comes to mind which would address the Gemorah's concern about lukewarm water very nicely: Pour the grain or flour into water that is already boiling. Why does the Gemorah not even suggest this answer? That answer seems to fit much more nicely with the Beraisa while addressing the Gemorah's concern just as well.

Note: I am a bit biased, this question jumped out at me from a wish that oatmeal and cream of wheat would be Kosher for Pesach.

Comment: Your suggested answer is just as redundant. That's the case of Chalut.

Comment: Re cream of wheat: Manischewitz sells a [Hot Wheat Cereal](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0083CP8V8), assuming you eat gebroktz.

Comment: Pouring the grain or flour into water that is already boiling will reduce the temperature of the water. It would have to be done extremely carefully so that the heat supplied to the water keeps it boiling while the flour is added.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Alternatively you can warm up the dry kernels so that adding them to the water actually raises the water temperature!

Comment: @DoubleAA Good practical advice! Why does the Gemora not suggest this answer?