# KfP-for-Ashk'nazim rice cakes… now what if they're soaked?

Tags: passover, ashkenazi, current-events, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

A rabbi visited a ricecake factory, found that the rice never became wet in the process of manufacture (and was sifted well to be sure it's only rice), and decided that the ricecakes, which are anyway certified as kosher for Passover for those who eat *kitniyos*, are also kosher for Passover for those who don't. ([A small amount of more detail is available in Hebrew](http://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%96-%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97/) and [an even smaller amount in translation to English](http://lifeinisrael.blogspot.co.il/2018/03/interesting-psak-b-rice-cakes-are-not.html).)

Assuming one follows that ruling, can he also eat the ricecakes if (after purchase, say) they are soaked in water awhile? Does the puffing render them imperious to the quasi-leavening (what *Chazal* call rotting) that rice undergoes, or is there still a concern of such (or of the presence of grain) so that they cannot be eaten once soaked?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A1%D7%92_%D7%92 for wheat, but whether or not one should be similarly stringent for Kitniyot I can't say [and it is probably just a judgement call of the Posek since there's no real Minhag here]. See too https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28040/759

Comment: This question seems to assume that the problem of kitniyos may be the fact that rice undergoes "quasi-leavening." I don't think this is correct

Comment: @wfb I'm not sure that was intended as an assumption, but arguably that is the Arukh HaShulchan's position.